# Safari renders element of array in different order on each render

Tags: reactjs, safari

I have the following code:

```
Object.values(data).map((user) => {
  <div>
    <User key={user.id} user={user} />
  <div>
})
```

And the user has an ability to add new users through the UI, which get added to the `data` object and hence triggers a render.

It's working perfectly fine on all browsers (Chrome, Edge, IE) except from Safari. (version 13.1.2)
On Safari, almost each re-render of that users list changes the display order of those users in the UI.

Why could it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no JavaScript standard that says getting keys or values from an object should come in a certain order:

According to mdn [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)

> The Object.values() method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property values, in the same order as that provided by a for...in loop

And following the [for...in link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) it says:

> A for...in loop iterates over the properties of an object in an arbitrary order (see the delete operator for more on why one cannot depend on the seeming orderliness of iteration, at least in a cross-browser setting).

The reason it isn't guaranteed in a particular order was because of IE but since Safari is new IE it has taken over the torch of unpredictability.

If item order are important you should store them in an array, Set or Map.

Comment: Is there a reason `Object.values` maintains the order in other browsers? (the ones i mentioned it's working in)

Comment: @Gambit2007 It would "work" most of the time but browser creators are under no obligation to implement getting keys, values or entries from an object in a certain order. I tried with safari 13.1.1 and got entries in the same order every time. Not sure if you can report it as a bug since there is no specification saying it needs to be in a certain order.

Comment: Interesting.. ok, I'll try using something else! Last question - why did you mean by "Safari is the new IE"?

Comment: Can't talk for @HMR but I'll try my best: just as IE back in the day, Safari today refuses to align itself with other browsers when it comes to standards; the way it handles your CSS and JS is highly unpredictable, an testing on other browsers tends to give different results; and some of Apple's practices with it seem purely [anti-competition, anti-web](https://www.safari-is-the-new-ie.com/) and [anti-developers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63358968/debugging-iphone-safari-from-a-pc-without-an-apple-device). When deploying an app today, Safari tends to be a dev's greatest fear.

Comment: Ok got it. But what about the property key order that was introduced in ES6? https://medium.com/better-programming/objects-order-in-javascript-faed6b35de0e

Comment: (just to make it clear, i'm talking about `getOwnPropertyNames`)

Comment: @Gambit2007 Looks like it is a bug because the specification says [Object.entries](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-object.entries) uses [EnumerableOwnProperties](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-enumerableownproperties) that gets properties in a certain order. I have always tried to avoid using objects when I need to enumerate over the entries in a certain order. If you store it in redux then I'd advice using an array or array and object where the array has the keys in the order you need them to be in.

Comment: Yeah i think i will switch to an array.

So to sum up: with all functions (`.keys()`, `.values()`, `.entries()`, `for .. in .. `, the iteration order is a combination of the insertion order for strings keys, and ascending order for number-like keys? (starting ES6, when it's become a part of the specification)

And if that's not the case, it's probably a bug?

Comment: @Gambit2007 Yes, that's correct. I think MDN needs to update the documentation.

Comment: Ok, got it. Thanks @HMR for all of the clarifications :)